# Is 'ols' function in Econometrics toolbox in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, linear-regression

I am trying to run a code which calls the function `OLS`. `reg=ols(y,X)`. I am getting an error saying that ols is an undefined function for input of type double. Is ols a function in the econometrics toolbox or do we create a separate ols function? I have checked  the working directory and the toolbox is added to the path. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you tell us more about the code that you're trying to run? Where did you find it? Could you ask the author of the code for help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have `ols` either and I have the econometrics toolbox. I'm guessing you are looking for some functions in File Exchange, most likely the [Toolkit on Econometrics and Economics Teaching](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32601-toolkit-on-econometrics-and-economics-teaching).

Comment: @user2848498 You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer (the tick mark on the left) so that your question appears as been answered.